# Do we have any option to configure one way replication in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have configured DR and DC sides in Cassandra replication. What I want is, I want to configure replication from DC to DR but not from DR to DC.

Do we have the option to mark DR nodes readonly?

Main challenge is, application team want to keep configuration like, DR application should point to DR nodes and DC applications should point to DC node. But they don't want to replicate DR data(May be test data) to DC until we'll switch to live traffic to DR.

Another thing, they agree if we can protect DR node from write queries.

Answer (score 4):

That isn't possible at all. All DCs in Cassandra operate in active-active mode. There is no concept of passive/DR mode.

In any case, unless you are writing to the DR DC all writes will be coming from the "primary" DC in your cluster. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. If your main intent is to use `DR` nodes as read only nodes, you can configure your clients to write on `DC` nodes.

Comment: Edited my problem statement with little more explanation.

Comment: We can't achieve one way replication among datacenters. There is no such configuration. You can only control where you write. Once written Cassandra will make sure that all replicas(according to your configuration) have that data.

Answer (score 1):

DataStax DSE has [Advanced Replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/advReplication/advrepArchitecture.html) which provides hub-and-spoke capabilities.  However, this is only available the Enterprise Edition, not in open source Apache Cassandra.